# when i use a text object i see text in the background that is not suppose to be there. what am i doing wrong that causes extra text to appear?

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object

So I am using a text object for a game over screen in BGE. i use the code:

```
if B ['GAME_OVER'] == True:
    T.text= 'Game Over \nYou Lose'
```

the problem is that at the starting point of the text object the word 'Text' appears directly over the first word. i use this in other places but it dosen't have the same problem. is there something i can check to find the issue or a setting i might have messed up in the process?

Comment: When is "Text" visible? When you start the game, or when you set the text "Game Over \nYou Lose"?

Comment: What is the "first word"? Is it "Game"?

Comment: When I set the text it is visible.

Comment: I would like to see screenshots. One when before the text is set and one after the text is set.

Comment: Okay I have no problem posting the blend because this is just in trial phase. If you start the game and either win, lose, or push the T button after selecting an action then you will see the error I'm taking about.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x3yel9sqdefc0jy/AADJkOsEtXwoQ80-bgeelUla?dl=0

Comment: I recommend to create a simple demo file that shows the issue. While doing so you might already discover a solution to your problem. (The dropbox file is 404 right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. All I had to do was use edit mode on the text object and remove the placeholder text

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a second text object there.

Comment: I checked again. There is absolutely only one text object.

Comment: No problem, just an idea.